# How to enable the "Build environment" session on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, continuous-integration, browserstack, cicd

I'm following [this documentation](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/jenkins#configuring-browserstack-local) on how to run [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) on [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/). However, I can't see to find the `Build Environment` session. I have tried to find a way to enable it, but no luck.

Can somebody tell me the steps to enable it? or point to an article online on how to do so?

**Build Environment session's screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem by converting the pipeline to a [freestyle project](https://www.guru99.com/create-builds-jenkins-freestyle-project.html). It seems it's only available when using a freestyle project pipeline.

Comment: [JENKINS-49917](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-49917) seems to indicate it does not support pipelines. Unfortunately, your post did not indicate it was for pipeline job.

Comment: @IanW thanks, you're absolutely right. I forgot to mention this crucial detail.

Comment: Maybe email support@browserstack.com and see if they can get cracking on implementing?